# How to require a mixin (from config) using compass and scss

Tags: css, rubygems, sass, compass-sass, mixins

I have not been able to successfully install a compass plugin(?) I use the require in my config and would appreciate any help.

I was planning to test this:
http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/cross-browser-rgba-support/

The steps are rather simple, install via terminal, require at the top of config and finally include the mixin..(as seen in the url)

So I install via terminal, it seemed to have worked:>

```
➜  assets  sudo gem install compass-rgbapng
Password:
Fetching: chunky_png-1.2.9.gem (100%)
Successfully installed chunky_png-1.2.9
Fetching: fssm-0.2.10.gem (100%)
Successfully installed fssm-0.2.10
Fetching: compass-0.12.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed compass-0.12.2
Fetching: compass-rgbapng-0.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed compass-rgbapng-0.2.1
Parsing documentation for chunky_png-1.2.9
Installing ri documentation for chunky_png-1.2.9
Parsing documentation for fssm-0.2.10
Installing ri documentation for fssm-0.2.10
Parsing documentation for compass-0.12.2
Installing ri documentation for compass-0.12.2
Parsing documentation for compass-rgbapng-0.2.1
Installing ri documentation for compass-rgbapng-0.2.1
4 gems installed
➜  assets  compass watch
```

I add the require at the top of my compass config file:>

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require "rgbapng"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/assets/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

and finally in my mixins scss file I import the mixin:>

```
@import "rgbapng";
```

I then start sass watching again and get this error?

```
 ➜  assets  compass watch                   
 >>> Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
 >>> Change detected at 17:00:17 to: helpers/_mixins.scss
     error sass/base.scss (Line 1 of sass/helpers/_mixins.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: rgbapng.
```

can anyone point me in the right direction..

Comment: I have run into similar (albeit not exactly) problems when working on different versions of Zurb Foundation. Sometimes you have to specify the dependency that the gem requires. 

For example my config.rb file:

`# Require any additional compass plugins here.

require "sassy-math"

require "modular-scale"

require "compass"

gem "zurb-foundation", "=3.2.2"
require "zurb-foundation"
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'timestamp.rb')`

Perhaps try adding compass as a depencency?

Comment: **Perhaps try adding compass as a dependency? - require "compass"??

Comment: Yes, try putting `require "compass"` in your config.rb file in the same place as your `require "rgbapng"`

Comment: I tired this with no luck..

# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require "compass"
require "rgbapng"

Comment: Any chance that you need to specify the compass directory when including the gem in your stylesheets? Like `@import "compass/rgbapng"`

Comment: Sounds like something to do with your Ruby environment. Are you using anything like RVM, or do you have a bundler Gemfile file in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It randomly started working.. I think ther terminal was reset a few times before it started working properly